# C++ Design Pattern Strategy - Save/Load

Tags: c++, design-patterns

#### [1/2] Context

I'm using the Strategy Design Pattern to perform Save/Load within an application I've been coding since a couple of months...

Finally I come up with

- a **Model** (sub-classed by **Array** and **Graph** among others)
- two abstract I/O classes **ModelReader** and **ModelWriter** which are strategies that can be used to perform load/save.

Subsequently, I create several concrete strategies and thus were born **ArrayXmlWriter** and **GraphXmlWriter** which are dedicated to saving array and graph data to XML files. Now let's see the code snippets below and then I'll ask my questions.

```
// somewhere in ArrayXmlWriter

for(ArrayItem *item : array->items()) {
    // first write ModelItem attributes to a stream

    stream.writeAttribute("value",      item->value());
    stream.writeAttribute("brushColor", QVariant(item->brushColor()).toString());
    stream.writeAttribute("fontFamily", item->fontFamily());
    ...

    // then write ModelShapedItem attributes to a stream

    stream.writeAttribute("kind",    QVariant(item->shapeKind()).toString());
    stream.writeAttribute("rounded", QVariant(item->isRounded()).toString());
    ...

    // ArrayItem has no specific attributes
}
```

Indeed ArrayItem inherits from ModelShapedItem which inherits from ModelItem: **ModelItem <-- ModelShapedItem <-- ArrayItem**.

Now let's see the second snippet:

```
// somewhere in GraphXmlWriter

for(GraphVertex *vertex: graph->vertices()) {
    // first write ModelItem attributes to a stream

    same code as above

    // then write ModelShapedItem attributes to a stream

    same code as above

    // ModelNode has no specific attributes

    // then write GraphVertex attributes to a stream

    write successors to the stream
}
```

Here is the hierarchy involving the GraphVertex class: **ModelItem <-- ModelShapedItem <-- ModelNode  <-- GraphVertex**.

Now here are my questions:

#### [2/2] Questions

**Is there a way to avoid duplicating code (as shown above)?** Indeed one way to achieve that will be to add a virtual function (taking the stream as parameter) to the ModelItem class. We could then override that function in sub-classes. That means if a **GraphJsonWriter** were to be created one day, the ModelItem class and its involved sub-classes would also be edited (since another virtual function should be added).

**Now** let's imagine the classes shown above but the concrete strategies are part of some library I'm dynamically linking to: that means I have no access to their code. **How could one avoid code duplication without using dynamic_cast?**

I'm not sure if I'm posting on the right forum. If I'm not, feel free to advise me by telling me which forum suits the most. I actually want to know if there is a way to achieve what I want to do.

Thanks and sorry if my english is not that good.

Comment: I would implement a function of stream and item in the ModelWriter class.

Comment: I may not be understanding correctly but if the code duplication is within classes whose code you don't have access to, why would you care about the duplication in that code? Even if you do care, there is nothing you can do about it AFAIK.

Comment: I'm the one who wrote all the code. But assuming I was linking to a 3rd party library just helps me figure out whether I'm coding the right way or not.

@Cristi: What you suggest will surely work. But either we should use dynamic_cast (to convert the given item to the right type and then manipulate its attributes) or we should define as many functions (of stream and item) as there are types within the hierarchy. For instance function1(Stream&, const ModelItem&), function2(Stream&, const ModelShapedItem&), ...

Finally it seems there is no magic solution to what I want to do.

Comment: You don't have to implement all function1. You can implement the needed functionality in the ModelItem or ModelShapeItem class. Depending on how your code looks like you can simplify a lot.

Comment: I do not believe you need to use dynamic casts. You can move all the functionality in the base class or declare the functions as virtual there.

Comment: Indeed I can implement the needed functionality in the ModelItem class and use C++ function overriding to make sure sub-classes share the smae services while using mother class services. See first paragraph in section "Questions" (in my original post). But doing it that way doesn't seem relevant since a Json reader/writer doesn't require any stream as the Xml reader does.

That said, I can't unserstand what you mean in your second comment. If by "base class" you refer to "ModelWriter", I'll way dynamic_cast is needed. If you refer to "ModelItem", I'll say you're right. --> See next comment.

Comment: But I can't merge the functionalities since in the real project there is a class named **ModelMultiShapedItem** inheriting from ModelItem and representing items for which switching between shapes is allowed.

For example a vertex can be a circle or a rectangle (and this change can be performed at run time). Whereas an edge doesn't support such actions. Here is a screenshot: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/8e48efe46e756e80f900584241c5c108ebc7fcef/68747470733a2f2f757365722e6f632d7374617469632e636f6d2f75706c6f61642f323031372f30312f32362f31343835343536393833393335385f696d6734372e706e67.

Comment: For me it seems to be a general design flaw! Why not splitting the "what to write" from "how to write". If that is done, you can simply call from derived class the base class of the "what to write" method which then calls the "how to write" method which was given as parameter itself. Another remark: Using a "Variant" seems also be a design flaw, because you loose the type information. I saw a lot of QT applications using that, but often this was the startpoint of unmaintainability.